How do you say Sz.-Nagy's name?
I don't actually remember ever hearing Béla Szőkefalvi-Nagy's name in any class (which would have been decades ago anyway), so I'm at a loss.  Do you just say "Nagy"?  Do you remember the whole "Szőkefalvi"?
Bonus question: Why is it abbreviated?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

It seems no one is entirely convinced of their own correctness, so I guess there's some leeway.  Here, I'll collate some points from the comments and my own research.
The "Sz.-" part could probably be ignored and people would understand — as when we talk about the "Erdős–Nagy theorem".  But to the extent that people pronounce it, it's something like "siz-" or "szah-".  My guess is that "s-" or "soo-" would also work, as the Hungarian IPA illustrations suggests "sző" would sound like "sö".  Of course, "sö-keh-fahl-vee" would probably count as a respectable effort.
The "Nagy" part may be pronounced (as I would have) "Nah-ghee" by Americans, just because that's what it looks like, but a more authentic pronunciation would evidently be "nodj" — or in IPA, "ˈnɒɟ" — for which there is a recording here.  Note that the "y" on the end doesn't actually make an "ee" sound.
As to why it appears this way, it seems that Béla Nagy would be one of the more common names in Hungary, so the addition of Szőkefalvi presumably helps narrow it down... but that's pretty long, so I guess some abbreviation is in order.  In any case, the man himself abbreviated it as such.  The biographical note in a memorial conference proceedings dedicated to him has this to say:

Béla Szőkefalvi-Nagy was born on July 29, 1913, in the city of
Kolozsvár in Transylvania, which was in the Austro-Hungarian Empire
at that time. His name refers to noble origin of the family;
actually, Szőkefalva is a small village near the town
Erzsébetváros, where his father was born. Since most of his
scientific papers were signed as B. Sz.-Nagy, we shall also use
this shortened form of his name.

Szőke is a village in Hungary, and "falva" translates to "village", with the "-i" ending presumably indicating that the family is from that place.  Also note that "szőke" translates as "blond", and is pronounced like "sö-keh".

No, not "soo-keh". That's a double acute accent on the "ő", so it's a long "ö" sound, like in German "schön". If you read IPA, it's /øː/; the whole name is /beːlɒ søːkɛfɒlvi nɒɟ/.

@TonyK Well, the Hungarian IPA illustrations specifically gives "shoot" as the English-vowel example for the Hungarian word "lő", for which its IPA form is indeed "løː".  Though the wikipedia version suggests "purr" instead of "shoot".  Meanwhile, google's pronunciation of "szőke" gives it more of an "oo".  But to be honest, this is splitting hairs my finely than I think I'm capable of.

I'm afraid you have completely misunderstood that vowel table! Those English words are not pronunciation guides, they are simply translations of the Hungarian example word. (You might have realised this, e.g. ujj 'finger, hat 'six'...)

Roughly CIRca fall vee NUDGE.

@TonyK Ah, you're right!  I'm used to looking at Wikipedia's tables which does have English approximations and not the translations — but for some reason the IPA journal's version came up first in my google search.  And I just didn't look at any other vowels.  Thanks for pointing that out.
